# Is SpringSource Tool Suite 2.6 Grails support broken?

Tags: spring, plugins, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have recently updated my STS from 2.5.2 to 2.6. Since then, each grails project shows an error in the **conf/spring/resources.groovy** file reading:
 `Description Resource Path Location Type
Internal compiler error: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/internal/compiler/ast/JDTClassNode, method: initialize signature: ()V) Bad access to protected data at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.JDTResolver.createClassNode(JDTResolver.java:461)  resources.groovy /GrailsProject/grails-app/conf/spring line 0   Java Problem`
The `resources.groovy` file is as good as empty (in default state), and if I delete it, the error is shown on the `DataSource.groovy`, so the file itself seems not to be the cause.
The used groovy compiler version is 1.7.3.
I have made a clean STS 2.6 install, installed the groovy and grails plugins and got the same error.
What could be the problem? And is there a solution to this not resulting in downgrading to 2.5.2 again? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your preferences Groovy -> Compiler.  Are you by any chance accidentally using Groovy 1.6?

---

EDIT

That didn't solve the problem, but as described in http://forum.springframework.org/showthread.php?p=357361, upgrade to the latest dev build of Groovy-Eclipse as well as Grails Tooling and that should work.

Comment: That was my first idea, but as I mentioned in the question, the compiler version in the preferences is 1.7.3, so I'm puzzled

Comment: Another user had a similar problem a little while ago.  This person upgraded to the latest dev build of Groovy-Eclipse and Grails tooling.  That seems to have fixed the problem.  http://forum.springframework.org/showthread.php?p=357361

Comment: Thank you, installing the snapshots fixed the issue. Could you please update your answer to include the actual solution (installing the snapshots) so I can accept it? I could do it myself if you're ok with it.